# styling third level of menu not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

In my attempt to create mega menu, im stuck with styling third level of submenu. First submenu (li ul)  is not displayed (display: none). Then i have jquery script that shows that submenu on hover ( li ul - first level ). If window is less then 768px then the click function is activated (for touch screens).

My problem is when i want to style the third level sub menu ( submenu of submenu - li - ul - li - ul ) no style is applied - i want it to be shown always, but is hidden, display: none is applied on that UL but i styled it as display: block. So its only shown when i hover its LI element (li ul li hover).

So basically what im trying to do is that first submenu (li - ul) is activated on hover (or click for phones) but that second submenu (submenu of submenu) is allways visible. When i try to style it i access it like this: li ul li ul, and that is not working. How should i access it? Also when i try to hover that third level submenu, menu closes and i did not specify it like that in jquery.

HTML

```
<div class="menu-container">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>This is mega menu</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
}
.menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
.menu:before,
.menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.menu:after {
  clear: both;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1.5em 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: 0 none;
}
.menu li ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  background: none;
  float: left;
}
.menu li ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  padding: .2em 0;
}
.menu li ul li ul {
  display: block;
}
.menu li ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
960px
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
TABLETS
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
/* ––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
MOBILE 100%
–––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .menu > li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu > li > ul {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu > li > ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".menu li").hover(function () {
        if ($(window).width() > 767) {
            $('.menu ul li ul').not($(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(200)).hide();
        }
    });
    $(".menu li").click(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
            $('.menu ul li ul').not($(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(200)).hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/riogrande/pen/ZbaeKa

Comment: You're giving too much code with too large description (in *one* paragraph), which are hard to read and understand. If you want anyone to keep their eyes on your question and not close it immediately after seeing it, try to simplify the code and give a shorter and cleaner question. Best if a demo is added.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion I edited my post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS selector `.menu li ul li ul li` will select all list items in the 3rd level submenu or lower. As sodawillow mentioned, you can either use classes or the direct descendent selector `>` to fine tune styles for specific submenu levels.

---

The following snippets will fix the submenu hovering effect to be more intuitive - by having all menus hidden until its parent is hovered over.

JavaScript - replace the entire fade/hide statement with this:

```
$(this).children("ul").fadeToggle(200);
```

CSS:

```
.menu li ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
```

---

If you want the second submenu to be visible when the first submenu is visible, the jQuery selector should be `$(".menu > li")` instead to select just the first submenu, and the CSS can be left as is.

Comment: Thanks, this works, exactly what i wanted. And thanks for jquery hint to!

Answer (score 1):

These selectors may target the same li elements, the first one is very broad and cancels the rules for the following ones :

```
.menu li ul {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
  left: 0;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

.menu li ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  width: 25%;
  background: none;
  float: left;
}

.menu li ul li ul {
  display: block;
}

.menu li ul li ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

You may use the `>` selector to target only direct children, but I'd strongly advise using classes instead, to help separating styles between levels :

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <ul class="menu-level1">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
            <ul class="menu-level2">
                <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a>
                    <ul class="menu-level3">
                        <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ovo je nesto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Who are we?</a>
            <ul class="menu-level2">
                <li>This is mega menu</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```